# Safari ipad returns int as a result of parseFloat

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have a value of 9.23 which I get like this:

```
alert(parseFloat(data.x));
```

data.x is 9.23.
In Google Chrome in the alert I get 9.23, and on ipad Safari I get just 9. Why is this happening?

Comment: If the value is 9.23, why are you using parseFloat at all?

Comment: @Srcee Are you using the correct "dot"? (so, `9.23` instead of `9,23`, for example).

Comment: @Srcee are you completely certain that Safari receives the string `9.23`? Browser-sent locales could cause the server to send `9,23` in some instances.

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger Well the number is double and I return it with string.format("{0:0.00}"

Comment: @Srcee: assuming you are using C#, it looks like `"."` can become a `,` according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierPt)

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger No. I'm stuck

Comment: @Srcee: can you try running this jsfiddle on the iPad: http://jsfiddle.net/yx2YW/1/

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comment, you are formatting the number server-side using C#. I heavily doubt that the Safari implementation of `parseFloat` is broken and suspect that the number is formatted in a locale-dependent way using `,` as a separator. You can avoid this using

```
value.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```